# Visual basic / visual studio 2010 windows form loads blank

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2010

I am new to visual basic so hopefully this is a simple question. I have a menu with buttons to call different forms. The forms are designed and have labels and text fields and buttons and so on. From the main menu I have tried calling the forms two different ways. One way the forms open and look correct and function. The other way the form opens as a small blank square with no fields. Ultimately I want to create a set of List objects when the main menu opens and pass them back and forth to the other forms for input and processing. I'm using parallel Lists as a temporary database for a simple school lab. I just don't see what is wrong with the way I am calling the form. I haven't even bothered worrying about passing the List objects properly yet.

```
Public Class frmMain

Dim arrGames As New List(Of String)
Dim arrDates As New List(Of String)
Dim arrPrices As New List(Of Decimal)
Dim arrSeats As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub btnEnterGames_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnterGames.Click
    'NewEnter.Visible = True
    Dim frmEnter As New NewEnter(arrGames, arrDates, arrPrices, arrSeats)
    frmEnter.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub btnReports_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReports.Click
    'Reports.Visible = True
    Dim frmReports As New Reports(arrGames, arrDates, arrPrices, arrSeats)
    frmReports.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnSellTickets_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSellTickets.Click
    'SellTickets.Visible = True
    Dim frmSell As New SellTickets(arrGames, arrDates, arrPrices, arrSeats)
    frmSell.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

This is the code for the form NewEnter. I have the New routine which accepts the 4 Lists and basically does nothing else. Doing the "'NewEnter.Visible = True" in the main menu will load the form correctly but I have to comment out the New sub routine in the forms or there is an error.

```
Public Class NewEnter

Private _arrGames As List(Of String)
Private _arrDates As List(Of String)
Private _arrPrices As List(Of Decimal)
Private _arrSeats As List(Of Integer)

Sub New(ByVal arrGames As List(Of String), ByVal arrDates As List(Of String), ByVal arrPrices As List(Of Decimal), ByVal arrSeats As List(Of Integer))
    ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
    '  _arrGames = arrGames
    '  _arrDates = arrDates
    '  _arrPrices = arrPrices
    '  _arrSeats = arrSeats
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveGame_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveGame.Click

    Dim arrGames As New List(Of String)
    Dim arrDates As New List(Of String)
    Dim arrPrices As New List(Of Decimal)
    Dim arrSeats As New List(Of Integer)

    Dim strGame As String
    Dim strPrice As String
    Dim strSeats As String
    Dim intSeats As Integer
    Dim decPrice As Decimal
    Dim bolGameErr As Boolean
    Dim bolDateErr As Boolean
    Dim bolPriceErr As Boolean
    Dim bolSeatErr As Boolean

    strGame = txtGame.Text
    strPrice = txtPrice.Text
    strSeats = txtSeats.Text

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~verify a game is entered
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strGame) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strGame) Then
        bolGameErr = True
    Else
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~verify price is numeric
        If IsNumeric(strPrice) Then
            decPrice = strPrice
            '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~verify seats are numeric
            If IsNumeric(strSeats) Then
                intSeats = Convert.ToInt32(strSeats)
                ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ add elements to array lists
                arrGames.Add(New String(strGame))
                arrDates.Add(dtpDate.Text)
                arrPrices.Add(New Decimal(decPrice))
                arrSeats.Add(intSeats)

                lblSaveSuccessful.Visible = True
                ClearInput()
                ' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ add elements to array lists
            Else
                bolSeatErr = True
            End If

        Else
            bolPriceErr = True
        End If
    End If

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Check flags for input errors
    If bolDateErr = True Then
        lblErr.Text = "Invalid date"
        lblErr.Visible = True
    End If
    If bolGameErr = True Then
        lblErr.Text = "Must enter a game name"
        lblErr.Visible = True
        txtGame.Focus()
    End If
    If bolDateErr = True And bolGameErr = True Then
        lblErr.Text = "Must enter a game name and valid date"
        lblErr.Visible = True
        txtGame.Focus()
    End If
    If bolPriceErr = True Then
        lblPriceErr.Visible = True
        txtPrice.Text = ""
        txtPrice.Focus()
    End If
    If bolSeatErr = True Then
        lblSeatErr.Visible = True
        txtSeats.Text = ""
        txtSeats.Focus()
    End If
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Check flags for input error
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Display output
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    lblData.Text = arrGames.Count.ToString
    Do While i < arrGames.Count
        lblData.Text = Convert.ToString(arrGames(i)) & " on " & Convert.ToString(arrDates(i)) & " Price: " & _
            Convert.ToString(arrPrices(i)) & " Available Seats: " & Convert.ToString(arrSeats(i))
        i += 1
    Loop
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Display output

    lblData.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub ClearInput()
    'lblErr.Visible = False
    'lblPriceErr.Visible = False
    'lblSeatErr.Visible = False
    txtGame.Text = ""
    txtPrice.Text = ""
    txtSeats.Text = ""
    txtGame.Focus()
End Sub

Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Me.Visible = True
    'Me.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood
    'Me.ResumeLayout()
    'Me.Activate()
    'Me.Focus()
    'Me.Show()
    'Me.lblGameHdr.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: it looks like you created your own constructor instead of using the one VS needs to have.  Without it, no controls or form props will initialize. Delete your your `Sub New`, then in the Code window, select the form object in the left drop down, then in the right dropdown, select New.  Pay attention to the designer warnings listed there.  I'd actually add a `AddData` method (or set of props) and pass the stuff that way rather than in the ctor in this case.

Comment: Add InitializeComponents() to your constructor class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add InitializeComponent() to your constructor class. 
This is added by default to the New (constructor) function of all Visual Basic forms. It requires it to set-up the UI components on the form.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. I can't believe I didn't find that answer somewhere already. Thank you!

Comment: If you could 1-up my answer that'd be awesome, lol. I've made the same mistake before, so I know how frustrating it can be.

Comment: my reputation is too low to increase the public score :(

Comment: oh okay. Glad I could help anyways, good luck with your project.